# Displaying posts only form a category that has same name as the current page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

My theme supports different post types - one of those is portfolio posts. I'm trying to display portfolio posts on a page but only from one specific category - the one that has the same name as the current page.

Example:
I have portfolio posts in categories: red, green, blue.
I have pages named: red, green, blue.
Now I would like to display on page "red" only post from category "red".

I'm very new to wordpress and making websites in general.

I tried to read a bit about it and found a way to display posts from certain category only:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'portfolio_category=red' );?>
```

From there I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'portfolio_category=$pagename' );?>
```

Here is full code of the page template I'm talking about:
http://pastebin.com/LxetTnUz

Comment: pastebin link isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this word press function get the page slug which is basically name of the page

```
<?php echo get_page_template_slug( $post->ID ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug